# typescript, same types cleaning

Tags: typescript, swagger, swagger-codegen

after a swagger to typescript codegen of a big json file i need to clean typescript types that has the same content and all generated types declaration that put a new type equal to another type.
Example:

```
export type V2AuthenticationResource = {
  grantType?: string;
  password?: string;
  refreshToken?: string;
  token?: string;
  username?: string;
};

export type PostRestapiV20AuthBodyParameters = V2AuthenticationResource;
export type DeleteRestapiV20AuthBodyParameters = V2AuthenticationResource;

PostRestapiV20Auth(
  body: PostRestapiV20AuthBodyParameters //here i can use V2AuthenticationResource instead
): ApiResponse<V2AuthenticationResponse> {
  const path = "/restapi/v2.0/auth";
  return this.requestFactory(
    path,
    undefined,
    body,
    undefined,
    "POST"
  );
}

DeleteRestapiV20Auth(
  body: DeleteRestapiV20AuthBodyParameters //here i can use V2AuthenticationResource instead
): ApiResponse<V2AuthenticationResponse> {
  const path = "/restapi/v2.0/auth";
  return this.requestFactory(
    path,
    undefined,
    body,
    undefined,
    "DELETE"
  );
}
```

or

```
export type V2DeviceData = {
  deviceId: string;
  deviceName: string;
}
export type V2DeviceInfo = {
  deviceId: string;
  deviceName: string;
}
```

the code works fine, i only want to reduce filesize because i've hundreds of that repetitions.
I'm using Visual Studio Code, i tried to search for an extension but couldn't find anything.

Comment: The root problem is with your Swagger file. Swagger can declare commonalities in DTOs which can then be used to generate cleaner client library. Are you the author of the Swagger file - or can you manually improve the Swagger file before you run it through the TypeScript generation program?

Comment: I'm not the author, i can modify the json file before the codegen step, but i've already worked a lot to fix issues and now it works... dont want to start over :/

Comment: I was thinking that a tool should be there, it seems strange to me to be the only one who has run into this problem. In large projects a tool to "clean up" the same types with different names would be useful

Comment: Such a tool wouldn't be as useful as you think because different types with identical shapes can still have different semantics - and types are all about semantics.

Comment: I agree, of course the tool should inspect the code to avoid overwriting types and interfaces that are extended from other parts of the code. However it is not a big problem because after the build the file size remains the same regardless of the types used. It's just ugly to look at and uncomfortable to edit ...

Comment: "However it is not a big problem because after the build the file size" - yes, because TypeScript has **type-erasure**, but ultimately the problem you have is a data-quality problem, not a TypeScript type problem.